# Can't access to ec2 instance using putty or filezilla after run the JBOSS AS7 service

Tags: amazon-ec2, jboss7.x, putty, filezilla

I am try to deploy a web app using ec2 instance . I used JBOSS AS7 . I deployed the web application to ec2 instance. and i create a jboss service that start automatically . now it's started . Problem is i can access web application using browser but for editing and altering application i used putty and filezilla . Now i can't access to that instance using putty or filezilla. Can anyone help on this ? 
Thanks in advance .

Comment: Do you receive any errors in putty or filezilla? Did you make any changes in AWS Security Groups or Network ACLs?

Comment: i got " Network error : connection refuse " in both @VladimirMukhin

Comment: I didn't change anything in AWS Security Group or Network @VladimirMukhin

Comment: It looks like an issue with the JBOSS itslef, not with AWS network. Maybe some port conflict or something else. I have searched and found the issue that looks similar to what you have:
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ENTESB-2560
Consider contacting RedHat support in order to resolve this.

Comment: @VladimirMukhin thanks for your support . I solved that problem. That problem was with my jboss user. In the service script i used as followed first " sudo -u jboss sh ${JBOSS_HOME}/bin/standalone.sh ". Then i change the line as "${JBOSS_HOME}/bin/standalone.sh " . Then it works fine.